# Moment generating functions and exponential problem

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Suppose $X,Y$ are random variables corresponding to mgfs $M_X(t)$ and $M_Y(t)$. Is there a function of X and Y such that its mgf is $M_X(t)+M_Y(t)$?

I think the question eventually becomes if I can find a function $f(X,Y)$, say, such that $e^{tX}+e^{tY}=e^t{f(X,Y)}$. Using some simple tricks I will have $f(X,Y)=\frac{ln(e^{tX}+e^{tY})}{t}.$ This is not at all helpful though, since it also relies on $t$. So I have no idea if there is something else I could do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum of two moment generating functions can never be a moment generating function. This is because any moment generating function had the value $1$ at $0$.

Comment: What if, say, we have the average of two mgf, which will take the value 1 at 0?  Is there such a function that allows us to do so ?

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent with given MGF's and $Z$ be $X$ with probability 0.5, $Y$ with probability 0.5. What is the MGF of $Z$?

Answer (score 2):

Without any further rearrangement, if you plug in $t=0$ at the left hand side of your first equation you will see that such a function cannot exist.